# Package name for CurrentDate class

Tags: actionscript-3, naming, nomenclature

I'm about to write a class called CurrentDate and need a solid package name. The obvious answers are com.destroytoday.date or com.destroytoday.time, but I'm not sure if I'll have more date-related classes in the future to justify an entire package. Are there any names I can use that would allow non-date-related classes in the future?

To be more specific about the class, it consists of static functions like toString() that auto-update a Date instance and return the current info.

Comment: `mydomain.utils` is where I put my classes that doesn't actually deserve an entire package for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy: destroy.time

Comment: This does make the most sense. The more I think of it, the more ideas I come up with for date/time-related classes :)

Answer (score 0):

The first namespaces I can think of, without to know the purpose of such classes are com.destroytoday.utility, com.dewstroytoday.utilities, com.destroytoday.support, com.destroytoday.helpers.

Answer (score 0):

What about com.destroytoday.generic?